# Computing the projection of a point onto an affine plane

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, optimization

I'm working on the following problem from my textbook:

> Determine the Euclidean projection of a point $y$ onto the following
>   hyperplane:
>
> $$ H = \left\{ z \in \mathbb{R}^n : a^{\top}z = b \right\} $$
>
> where $a$ is the normal vector of the hyperplane.

**My solution:** Observe that the projection of $y$ onto $H$ is the same as

$$
b + \text{proj}_{\tilde{H}}(y-b)
$$

where $\tilde{H} = \left\{ z \in \mathbb{R}^n : a^{\top} z = 0 \right\}$. The projection of $y-b$ onto $\tilde{H}$ is simply

$$
\frac{a^{\top}(y-b)}{||a||_2^2} a.
$$

Thus, the projection $y^*$ of $y$ onto $H$ is

$$
y^* = b + \frac{a^{\top}(y-b)}{||a||_2^2} a.
$$

I believe that this answer is correct, but the answer in my textbook is the following (there is no work shown):

$$
y^* = \frac{a^{\top}y - b}{||a||^2_2}a.
$$

Are these somehow equivalent, or did I make a mistake somewhere?

Comment: You're confused, I think. The $b$ thing is a scalar, so $y-b$ doesn't even make sense. I haven't checked thoroughly, but your book's answer looks correct, to me.

Answer (score 3):

So start by noting that a fixed point $x_0\in H$ satisfies $a^Tx_0=b$. Next note that:
\begin{equation}
 y-x_0 = (proj_H(y)-x_0)+\frac{a^T(y-x_0)}{||a||^2} a 
\end{equation}
We may isolate for $proj_H(y)$ to get:
$$ 
 y = proj_H(y) +\frac{(a^Ty-b)}{||a||^2}a \Leftrightarrow proj_H(y) = y-\frac{(a^Ty-b)}{||a||^2}a.
$$